# Fail to embed Flash by using Data uri scheme

Tags: html

i just want to embed a flash like this:

```
<object
data="data:application/x-shockwave-flash;base64,..."
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="movie"
value="data:application/x-shockwave-flash;base64,..."
/> </object>
```

but it just doesn't work. Did i make any mistake?

thankz

Answer (score 4):

That's because it doesn't work. Not only would you have a buffer overflow, but most browsers don't allow for the inclusion of Flash via Data URIs. If you need a good place to host your Flash, [Google Code](http://code.google.com/) works just fine.

Comment: i, too, am faced with this problem, my free hosts were blocking my file due to many thousand hits.  
google code saves the day